# How should we tag: "Pictionary: Ultimate Edition"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today we got [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46068/is-there-a-simple-way-to-export-your-free-draw-image-in-pictionary-ultimate-edi) about "Pictionary: Ultimate Edition". [pictionary-ultimate-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictionary-ultimate-edition) is 27 characters.

How should we tag it?  [pictionaryultimateedition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictionaryultimateedition)?

Comment: Is it too much to assume that Pictionary is similar enough to Pictionary-ultimate-edition that we can just drop the last two words from the title?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't know, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: I think as a rule, **omitting the hyphens is absolutely verboten** as search engines will then parse the whole thing as *a* word (`-` and other delimiters are interpreted as spaces).

Comment: At some point the only Pictionary question was deleted, meaning the relevant tags no longer exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags with hyphens removed have generally been avoided.  I'm not sure what the differences between the regular and ultimate editions are, but as Raven pointed out, that would be the most obvious tag to use if it is applicable.

If there are enough distinctions between the two games, my vote would be for either [pictionary-ultimate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictionary-ultimate) or [pictionary-ultimate-ed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictionary-ultimate-ed), as anyone searching for questions about the game will be able to easily identify it (especially with a helpful tag wiki).

Comment: [tag:Pictionary-Ultimate] seems perfectly acceptable.